# AspNetCore:2.1 not found

Tags: docker

Created a new .NET CORE 2.1 (preview) web app. Running it in local docker with Linux container
I am getting compiler error:

Error Building blobtest
Service 'blobtest' failed to build: manifest for microsoft/aspnetcore:2.1 not found.

My dotnetversion
C:\WINDOWS\system32>dotnet --version
2.1.300-preview2-008530

Comment: I created another project on .NET Core 2.0 and it is functioning as expected. I am going to downgrade the project. Maybe the docker just does not have the aspnetcore 2.1 yet

Comment: You can run on docker, they updated the images. You should get the lasted image as explained here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/02/27/announcing-net-core-2-1-preview-1/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

They have changed the repo for .NET Core 2.1 onwards to [microsoft/dotnet](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/dotnet/).
Change your FROM statement to reference microsoft/dotnet using the following tags:

- 2.1-sdk
- 2.1-aspnetcore-runtime
- 2.1-runtime

Documentation on how to upgrade can be found [here](https://github.com/aspnet/aspnet-docker/tree/master/2.1)

Comment: As in 2023, this is a wrong answer. Use: `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:2.1` and `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:2.1`. See: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-core-2-1-container-images-will-be-deleted-from-docker-hub/

Answer (score 14):

I had this issue as well. I thought I'd update this post to show the fix here. Thanks to [Marius Bidireac](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6403499/marius-bidireac) for the link to the resource.

Here is an excerpt from the original docker file

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0 AS base

FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 AS build
```

Here is an excerpt from the corrected docker file

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using GitLab CI, then these images don't work—maybe because they changed the names of the images again. See [official page](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-core-sdk/) on Docker.

If I used the labels suggested by this answer,

```
image: microsoft/dotnet:2.2
```

Then, it kept giving the errors,

> manifest for microsoft/dotnet:2.2 not found

Solution to this was to use the recent naming convention provided by Microsoft. Please see the Docker link I provided above. In my GitLab CI (.gitlab-ci.yml) file I used the following and it worked,

```
image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2
```

Now the build pipeline succeeds just fine.