# Failed to build: manifest for Microsoft/aspnetcore:2.1 not found Visual Studio 7.5.2 Mac OS X

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, docker, asp.net-core

I have created an Asp.net 2.1 Web API project using Visual Studio 7.5.2 in Mac OS X. I added a docker support to the project but while building, the project keep getting an error that states: `failed to build: manifest for microsoft/aspnetcore:2.1 not found.`.

**Docker file for project**

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.1 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.1 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY MeroRentalDev.sln ./
COPY Auth.API/Auth.API.csproj Auth.API/
RUN dotnet restore -nowarn:msb3202,nu1503
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/Auth.API
RUN dotnet build -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Auth.API.dll"]
```

**dockerfile.yml**

```
version: '3.4'

    services:
      auth.api:
        image: auth
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: Auth.API/Dockerfile
```

Full error details

```
Building: docker-compose (Debug)
Build started 8/06/2018 3:05:13 PM.
__________________________________________________
Project "/Users/macbook/Projects/MeroRentalDev/docker-compose.dcproj" (Build target(s)):

Target DockerResolveAppType:
    __________________________________________________
    Project "/Users/macbook/Projects/MeroRentalDev/docker-compose.dcproj" is building "/Users/macbook/Projects/MeroRentalDev/Auth.API/Auth.API.csproj" (DockerResolveAppType target(s)):

Target DockerResolveTargetFramework:
    __________________________________________________
    Project "/Users/macbook/Projects/MeroRentalDev/docker-compose.dcproj" is building "/Users/macbook/Projects/MeroRentalDev/Auth.API/Auth.API.csproj" (DockerResolveTargetFramework target(s)):

Target DockerResolveProjectInputAndOutput:
    __________________________________________________
    Project "/Users/macbook/Projects/MeroRentalDev/docker-compose.dcproj" is building "/Users/macbook/Projects/MeroRentalDev/Auth.API/Auth.API.csproj" (DockerResolveProjectInputAndOutput target(s)):

Target DockerPrepareForBuild:
    docker ps --filter "status=running" --filter "name=dockercompose763682937431840732_auth.api_" --format {{.ID}} -n 1
Target DockerBuildServiceReferences:
    __________________________________________________
    Project "/Users/macbook/Projects/MeroRentalDev/docker-compose.dcproj" is building "/Users/macbook/Projects/MeroRentalDev/Auth.API/Auth.API.csproj" (Build target(s)):

    Target _HandlePackageFileConflicts:
        Encountered conflict between 'Reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder/microsoft.netcore.app/2.1.0/ref/netcoreapp2.1/System.Collections.Immutable.dll' and 'Reference:/Users/macbook/.nuget/packages/system.collections.immutable/1.5.0/lib/netstandard2.0/System.Collections.Immutable.dll'.  Choosing 'Reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder/microsoft.netcore.app/2.1.0/ref/netcoreapp2.1/System.Collections.Immutable.dll' because it comes from a package that is preferred.
        Encountered conflict between 'Reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder/microsoft.netcore.app/2.1.0/ref/netcoreapp2.1/System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll' and 'Reference:/Users/macbook/.nuget/packages/system.diagnostics.diagnosticsource/4.5.0/lib/netstandard1.3/System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll'.  Choosing 'Reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder/microsoft.netcore.app/2.1.0/ref/netcoreapp2.1/System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll' because it comes from a package that is preferred.
        Encountered conflict between 'Reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder/microsoft.netcore.app/2.1.0/ref/netcoreapp2.1/System.Reflection.Metadata.dll' and 'Reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder/system.reflection.metadata/1.6.0/lib/netstandard2.0/System.Reflection.Metadata.dll'.  Choosing 'Reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder/microsoft.netcore.app/2.1.0/ref/netcoreapp2.1/System.Reflection.Metadata.dll' because it comes from a package that is preferred.
        Encountered conflict between 'Reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder/microsoft.netcore.app/2.1.0/ref/netcoreapp2.1/System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml.dll' and 'Reference:/Users/macbook/.nuget/packages/system.runtime.serialization.xml/4.3.0/ref/netstandard1.3/System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml.dll'.  Choosing 'Reference:/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder/microsoft.netcore.app/2.1.0/ref/netcoreapp2.1/System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml.dll' because AssemblyVersion '4.1.4.0' is greater than '4.1.1.0'.
        Encountered conflict between 'Platform:Microsoft.Win32.Registry.dll' and 'Runtime:/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder/microsoft.win32.registry/4.5.0/lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.Win32.Registry.dll'.  Choosing 'Platform:Microsoft.Win32.Registry.dll' because it comes from a package that is preferred.
        Encountered conflict between 'Platform:System.Collections.Immutable.dll' and 'Runtime:/Users/macbook/.nuget/packages/system.collections.immutable/1.5.0/lib/netstandard2.0/System.Collections.Immutable.dll'.  Choosing 'Platform:System.Collections.Immutable.dll' because it comes from a package that is preferred.
        Encountered conflict between 'Platform:System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll' and 'Runtime:/Users/macbook/.nuget/packages/system.diagnostics.diagnosticsource/4.5.0/lib/netstandard1.3/System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll'.  Choosing 'Platform:System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll' because it comes from a package that is preferred.
        Encountered conflict between 'Platform:System.Reflection.Metadata.dll' and 'Runtime:/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder/system.reflection.metadata/1.6.0/lib/netstandard2.0/System.Reflection.Metadata.dll'.  Choosing 'Platform:System.Reflection.Metadata.dll' because it comes from a package that is preferred.
        Encountered conflict between 'Platform:System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml.dll' and 'Runtime:/Users/macbook/.nuget/packages/system.runtime.serialization.xml/4.3.0/lib/netstandard1.3/System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml.dll'.  Choosing 'Platform:System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml.dll' because AssemblyVersion '4.1.4.0' is greater than '4.1.2.0'.
        Encountered conflict between 'Platform:System.Security.AccessControl.dll' and 'Runtime:/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder/system.security.accesscontrol/4.5.0/lib/netstandard2.0/System.Security.AccessControl.dll'.  Choosing 'Platform:System.Security.AccessControl.dll' because it comes from a package that is preferred.
        Encountered conflict between 'Platform:System.Security.Cryptography.Cng.dll' and 'Runtime:/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder/system.security.cryptography.cng/4.5.0/lib/netcoreapp2.1/System.Security.Cryptography.Cng.dll'.  Choosing 'Platform:System.Security.Cryptography.Cng.dll' because it comes from a package that is preferred.
        Encountered conflict between 'Platform:System.Security.Principal.Windows.dll' and 'Runtime:/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder/system.security.principal.windows/4.5.0/lib/netstandard2.0/System.Security.Principal.Windows.dll'.  Choosing 'Platform:System.Security.Principal.Windows.dll' because it comes from a package that is preferred.
        Encountered conflict between 'Platform:Microsoft.Win32.Registry.dll' and 'Runtime:/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder/microsoft.win32.registry/4.5.0/runtimes/unix/lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.Win32.Registry.dll'.  Choosing 'Platform:Microsoft.Win32.Registry.dll' because it comes from a package that is preferred.
        Encountered conflict between 'Platform:Microsoft.Win32.Registry.dll' and 'Runtime:/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder/microsoft.win32.registry/4.5.0/runtimes/win/lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.Win32.Registry.dll'.  Choosing 'Platform:Microsoft.Win32.Registry.dll' because it comes from a package that is preferred.
        Encountered conflict between 'Platform:System.Security.AccessControl.dll' and 'Runtime:/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder/system.security.accesscontrol/4.5.0/runtimes/win/lib/netcoreapp2.0/System.Security.AccessControl.dll'.  Choosing 'Platform:System.Security.AccessControl.dll' because it comes from a package that is preferred.
        Encountered conflict between 'Platform:System.Security.Cryptography.Cng.dll' and 'Runtime:/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder/system.security.cryptography.cng/4.5.0/runtimes/win/lib/netcoreapp2.1/System.Security.Cryptography.Cng.dll'.  Choosing 'Platform:System.Security.Cryptography.Cng.dll' because it comes from a package that is preferred.
        Encountered conflict between 'Platform:System.Security.Principal.Windows.dll' and 'Runtime:/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder/system.security.principal.windows/4.5.0/runtimes/unix/lib/netcoreapp2.0/System.Security.Principal.Windows.dll'.  Choosing 'Platform:System.Security.Principal.Windows.dll' because it comes from a package that is preferred.
        Encountered conflict between 'Platform:System.Security.Principal.Windows.dll' and 'Runtime:/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder/system.security.principal.windows/4.5.0/runtimes/win/lib/netcoreapp2.0/System.Security.Principal.Windows.dll'.  Choosing 'Platform:System.Security.Principal.Windows.dll' because it comes from a package that is preferred.
    Target GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute:
      Skipping target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
    Target _CoreGenerateRazorAssemblyInfo:
      Skipping target "_CoreGenerateRazorAssemblyInfo" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
    Target CoreGenerateAssemblyInfo:
      Skipping target "CoreGenerateAssemblyInfo" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
    Target CoreCompile:
      Skipping target "CoreCompile" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
    Target GenerateBuildDependencyFile:
      Skipping target "GenerateBuildDependencyFile" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
    Target GenerateBuildRuntimeConfigurationFiles:
      Skipping target "GenerateBuildRuntimeConfigurationFiles" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
    Target CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:
        Auth.API -> /Users/macbook/Projects/MeroRentalDev/Auth.API/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1/Auth.API.dll
Target DockerUpdateComposeVsGeneratedFiles:
    __________________________________________________
    Project "/Users/macbook/Projects/MeroRentalDev/docker-compose.dcproj" is building "/Users/macbook/Projects/MeroRentalDev/Auth.API/Auth.API.csproj" (DockerUpdateComposeVsGeneratedFiles target(s)):

    Copying file from "/Users/macbook/Projects/MeroRentalDev/obj/Docker/docker-compose.vs.debug.partial.g.yml" to "/Users/macbook/Projects/MeroRentalDev/obj/Docker/docker-compose.vs.debug.g.yml".
    Copying file from "/Users/macbook/Projects/MeroRentalDev/obj/Docker/docker-compose.vs.release.partial.g.yml" to "/Users/macbook/Projects/MeroRentalDev/obj/Docker/docker-compose.vs.release.g.yml".
Target DockerPrepareForLaunch:
    docker-compose  -f "/Users/macbook/Projects/MeroRentalDev/docker-compose.yml" -f "/Users/macbook/Projects/MeroRentalDev/docker-compose.override.yml" -f "/Users/macbook/Projects/MeroRentalDev/obj/Docker/docker-compose.vs.debug.g.yml" -p dockercompose763682937431840732 --no-ansi up -d --build --force-recreate --remove-orphans
    Building auth.api
    Step 1/3 : FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.1 AS base
    Service 'auth.api' failed to build: manifest for microsoft/aspnetcore:2.1 not found
    /Applications/Visual Studio.app/Contents/Resources/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/docker/MonoDevelop.Docker/MSbuild/Sdks/Microsoft.Docker.Sdk/build/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Docker.Compose.targets(363,5): error : Building auth.api
    /Applications/Visual Studio.app/Contents/Resources/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/docker/MonoDevelop.Docker/MSbuild/Sdks/Microsoft.Docker.Sdk/build/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Docker.Compose.targets(363,5): error : Service 'auth.api' failed to build: manifest for microsoft/aspnetcore:2.1 not found.
    /Applications/Visual Studio.app/Contents/Resources/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/docker/MonoDevelop.Docker/MSbuild/Sdks/Microsoft.Docker.Sdk/build/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Docker.Compose.targets(363,5): error : 
    /Applications/Visual Studio.app/Contents/Resources/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/docker/MonoDevelop.Docker/MSbuild/Sdks/Microsoft.Docker.Sdk/build/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Docker.Compose.targets(363,5): error : For more troubleshooting information, go to http://aka.ms/DockerToolsTroubleshooting
Done building target "DockerPrepareForLaunch" in project "docker-compose.dcproj" -- FAILED.

Done building project "docker-compose.dcproj" -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

/Applications/Visual Studio.app/Contents/Resources/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/docker/MonoDevelop.Docker/MSbuild/Sdks/Microsoft.Docker.Sdk/build/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Docker.Compose.targets(363,5): error : Building auth.api
/Applications/Visual Studio.app/Contents/Resources/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/docker/MonoDevelop.Docker/MSbuild/Sdks/Microsoft.Docker.Sdk/build/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Docker.Compose.targets(363,5): error : Service 'auth.api' failed to build: manifest for microsoft/aspnetcore:2.1 not found.
/Applications/Visual Studio.app/Contents/Resources/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/docker/MonoDevelop.Docker/MSbuild/Sdks/Microsoft.Docker.Sdk/build/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Docker.Compose.targets(363,5): error : 
/Applications/Visual Studio.app/Contents/Resources/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/docker/MonoDevelop.Docker/MSbuild/Sdks/Microsoft.Docker.Sdk/build/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Docker.Compose.targets(363,5): error : For more troubleshooting information, go to http://aka.ms/DockerToolsTroubleshooting
    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:07.03

---------------------- Done ----------------------

Build: 1 error, 0 warnings
```

I tried some solution from these links:

[AspNetCore:2.1 not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49798012/aspnetcore2-1-not-found)

[Cannot run Dot net core preview project on Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49795793/cannot-run-dot-net-core-preview-project-on-docker)

I updated the docker image to the latest version using the below command but still had the same issues.

```
Pulling from microsoft/dotnet

Pulling from microsoft/aspnetcore-build
```

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution but not sure this is the correct solution. Link - https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/aspnetcore/

Change the docker file like below

remove microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.1 to microsoft/aspnetcore-build

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY MeroRentalDev.sln ./
COPY Auth.API/Auth.API.csproj Auth.API/
RUN dotnet restore -nowarn:msb3202,nu1503
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/Auth.API
RUN dotnet build -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Auth.API.dll"]
```

**ASP.NET Core Runtime Docker Image**
This repository contains images for running published ASP.NET Core applications. These images contain the runtime only. Use microsoft/aspnetcore-build to build ASP.NET Core apps inside the container.

Answer (score 0):

They moved the docker images for 2.1 and you have to update the docker file that was automatically generated. The details are at https://github.com/aspnet/aspnet-docker/tree/master/2.1

Answer (score 0):

because Microsoft NET Core 2.1.x **from** docker image

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.1 AS base
```

**upgrade to** DockerHub image as next tag

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
```

As you see in github master image [link](https://github.com/aspnet/aspnet-docker/tree/master/2.1)